# JBoss 7 SNMP Adapter

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, snmp

I am looking for an SNMP adapter for JBoss 7.

So far I have found that there was [one developed](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossSNMPAdapter) for JBoss 5, and I also found a discussion [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/147085) where someone has taken the old code and started making [compatible with 7](http://code.google.com/p/commscale/source/list?repo=snmp-adaptor&name=master) but work is far from finished.

Anyone has any more information I am lacking on this subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after sometime, I will answer this question.

There is no more information on the subject. Work remains to be done. :)